# nib2objc can't work on OS 10.10.3

Tags: objective-c, nib

I have used the nib2objc tool before... and i works well.

but now ,i download the sources code of nib2objc from github,

and use the nib2objc command to transform xib files to .m file.

and i got this error , i don't know why. but i really need it rightness ..i hope somebody could help me ..thanks a lot.

here's the error message:

```
2015-07-08 23:28:12.792 nib2objc[843:36775] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9124203c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff86f9376e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91119bce -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
    3   nib2objc                            0x00000001050752db -[NSNumber(Nib2ObjcExtensions) tableViewCellSeparatorStyleString] + 139
    4   nib2objc                            0x000000010508153f -[UITableViewProcessor processKey:value:] + 399
    5   nib2objc                            0x000000010507ace1 -[Processor processObject:] + 577
    6   nib2objc                            0x0000000105076e3e -[NibProcessor process] + 654
    7   nib2objc                            0x0000000105073f37 main + 439
    8   nib2objc                            0x0000000105073d74 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: my mac os Version is 10.10.3  and my Xcode version is 6.3

Answer (score 1):

You will have to fix the error.

Look in the file that contains: `Nib2ObjcExtensions` and then look for `tableViewCellSeparatorStyleString`.

Comment: The `139` in the stack trace has nothing to do with line numbers. It's a byte offset into the compiled method. It could be line 10000 or anything else.

Comment: i am sorry .. i don't understand.. Is that you mean i should look for Nib2ObjcExtensions in the nib2objc source files?   and then?  wait for your help . thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In NSNumber+Nib2ObjcExtensions.h

Modify with  @"UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault"

- (NSString *)tableViewCellSelectionStyleString
  {
  NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone",
                     @"UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue",
                     @"UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray",
                     **@"UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault"**,nil];
  return [values objectAtIndex:[self intValue]];
  }

Try